# Why are gitlab jobs not sharing docker image?

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci

We have a Python project which required postgres docker image. The application runs fine on local system after starting docker container.
We have added two gitlab jobs, one is to start the  docker container and another is to run the python script, but it seems that the second job is not executing successfully which depends on the first job. Is there any reason of not having access of docker container in the 2nd job?

gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  image: docker/compose:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind

  script:
    - docker-compose down --v
    - docker-compose up -d

test:
  image: python:3.8
  needs: [build]
  variables:
    POETRY_VERSION: "1.1.15"
    POETRY_CORE_VERSION: "1.0.8"

  script:
    - python --version
    - POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true
    - pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION} poetry-core==${POETRY_CORE_VERSION}
    - poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi
    - poetry run pytest
```

Comment: Would you please add the `.gitlab-ci.yml` script?

Comment: Hi @Andromeda - added .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are trying to access the container from the previous job which I do not think is possible. If you want just a simple Postgres db, `services` in gitlab-ci would be one solution.

Comment: Actually we need to run pytest

Comment: Can we club it in one to make it works?

Comment: Of course, you can.

Comment: @Andromeda -  Could you please help us to do it?Actually I am not sure how to add two docker images in single gitlab job.

Comment: Ok, I add an answer and see if it works for you.

Comment: Please share your gitlab ci runner configuration as what you ask about depends on it. Which [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the docker compose project running in the test stage, add it to the test stage and up it there in the script.

A recent `docker:dind` service should include the docker compose plugin <sup>1</sup> (note it is without the dash, so "docker compose" and not "docker-compose").

```yaml
---

stages:
  - build # this may be required due to compose project requirements, so I kept it in the example
  - test

build: # this may be required due to compose project requirements, so I kept it in the example
  # ...

test:
  image: python:3.8
  services:
    - docker:dind

  needs: [build] # this may be required due to compose project requirements, so I kept it in the example
  variables:
    POETRY_VERSION: "1.1.15"
    POETRY_CORE_VERSION: "1.0.8"

  script:
    - >-
      docker compose down --v || :
      this looks borked, but we keep it for
      the original meaning of the OPs example
      as the meaning seems clear
    - docker compose up -d
    - python --version
    - POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true
    - pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION} poetry-core==${POETRY_CORE_VERSION}
    - poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi
    - poetry run pytest

# Also you may want to use `after_script:` to down the 
# project so it does not continue to run after test stage
# script has finished.

  after_script:
    - >-
      docker compose down --v || :
      this looks borked, but we keep it for
      the original meaning of the OPs example
      as the meaning seems clear
```

And further for the TLDR:

> Why gitlab jobs are not sharing docker image?

Because different jobs.

---

1. https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose

Comment: I did not see this image in the answer  image: docker/compose:latest

Comment: Yes, that is by intention. If you see the comment in the answer, docker:dind service in a recent version provides the docker compose plugin. _"**Important
 Docker Compose is now included as part of the Docker official image **"_ ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose

Comment: Hi @hakre - I tried solution provided by you and it gives docker: command not found

Comment: @Prashantkamble: Looks like it depends on the runner configuration. Perhaps create your own image that copies docker compose from docker and is from the python one you have. This should then run in your configuration and allows you to keep the script near to python as this is testing.

Comment: And please share your [gitlab ci runner configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) and the [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) you're using in your question, as what you ask about depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

To run `compose` and the `script` with the Python base image, you could do the following:

1. Add the script to a bash script like `script.sh`:

```bash
python --version
POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true
pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION} poetry-core==${POETRY_CORE_VERSION}
poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi
poetry run pytest
```

2. Change the job as follows:

```yaml
test:
  services:
    - docker:dind
  image: docker/compose:latest
  # needs: [build]
  variables:
    POETRY_VERSION: "1.1.15"
    POETRY_CORE_VERSION: "1.0.8"

  script:
    - docker-compose up -d
    - docker run --network=host -v $PWD/script.sh:/script.sh python:3.8 bash /script.sh
```

**Solution 2**

Install the Python for the `docker/compose` base image and run the script.

Comment: Hi @Andromeda - it seems that solution one does not install python?

Comment: Yes, you run `docker run python:3.8` which has the python installed.

Comment: Thanks but not sure why it saying script.sh is a directory

Comment: Where did you add the `scripts.sh`? It should be in the root directory.

Comment: I have added it root folder itselt.

Comment: Check this https://gitlab.com/monegim/test-ci/-/tree/c7c0faf3ead2fcfca319399c8279067eff9333c1 and passed pipeline https://gitlab.com/monegim/test-ci/-/jobs/4079065647